# ANDROID: Parsing XML

Tags: java, android

I'm not a developer, I just dabble in programming. One area I never understand is XML parsing. Sadly, for my latest "project" I need to do this very thing for an android app. Its a prototype that I am doing for work.

I have this XML (a mock-up file):

```
<feed version="201010011221" > 
  <period from="2010-10-01T10:08:34Z" to="2010-10-01T10:08:34Z"> 
    <lines> 
      <line id="SKI" name="Ski" shortname="ski" status="1 calls queued"> 
        <calls> 
          <call id="6584" created="2010-10-01T11:22:42Z">
            <booking>1275243</booking>
          </call> 
        </calls> 
      </line> 
      <line id="CRU" name="Cruise" shortname="cruise" status="0 calls queued"> 
        <calls /> 
      </line> 
      <line id="VIL" name="Villas" shortname="villas" status="2 calls queued"> 
        <calls> 
          <call id="25878" created="2010-10-01T10:22:42Z">
            <booking>1077244</booking>
          </call> 
          <call id="25878" created="2010-10-01T10:22:42Z">
            <booking>1077244</booking>
          </call> 
        </calls> 
      </line>
    </lines>
  </period> 
</feed>
```

I have some code that gets me a NodeList of each :

```
inputStream = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
Document document = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList lineNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("line");
```

I'm not sure what to do next. My code seems quite long for this. I've googled for better methods, but some cleaner code I found, I couldn't get to work.

Are there any good Android XML tutorials out there? Or can someone assist me with this code?

I need to get each  into a HashMap where String is the ID.

Line is class of all info shown.

Thanks
Neil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd n rather not use DOM as it has a bigger memory footprint. With DOM the whole XML structure is first loaded into memory and then it is being processed. This might not be the best solution for mobile development.

Use the SAX parser which comes with Android. It is an event driven approach. Every starting tag, content in between tags and end tag fire events when they occur. Actually it can handle more events but those are the most commonly used events. This means that the SAX parser processes each line one by one without loading the whole XML structure into memory first.

I will post an example for your particular problem tomorrow.

EDIT: Here is the promised content handler example.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MyContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

    private HashMap<String, Object> feed;
    private HashMap<String, Object> peroidContent;
    private HashMap<String, Object> callContent;
    private HashMap<String, Object> callsMap;
    private HashMap<String, Object> lineContent;
    private HashMap<String, Object> linesMap;

    private String text;
    private String callId;
    private String lineId;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        /* You can perform some action in this method
         * for example to reset some sort of Collection
         * or any other variable you want. It gets called
         * every time a document starts. */
        feed = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        // Gets called every time an opening tag is encountered.
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("FEED")) {
            /* We've found a "feed" opening tag so we capture its
             * version attribute and put it into our HashMap.*/
            feed.put("Version", atts.getValue("version"));
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("PEROID")) {
            peroidContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            peroidContent.put("From", atts.getValue("from"));
            peroidContent.put("to", atts.getValue("to"));
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("LINE")) {
            linesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("LINE")) {
            lineContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            lineId = atts.getValue("id");
            lineContent.put("name", atts.getValue("name"));
            lineContent.put("shortname", atts.getValue("shortname"));
            lineContent.put("status", atts.getValue("status"));
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CALLS")) {
            callsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CALL")) {
            callContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            callId = atts.getValue("Id");
            callContent.put("created", atts.getValue("created"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        /* Gets called every time in between an opening tag and
         * a closing tag if characters are encountered. */
        text = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // Gets called every time a closing tag is encountered.
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("FEED")) {
            feed.put("Peroid", peroidContent);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("PEROID")) {
            peroidContent.put("Lines", linesMap);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("LINES")) {
            linesMap.put(lineId, lineContent);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("LINE")) {
            lineContent.put("Calls", callsMap);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CALLS")) {
            callsMap.put(callId, callContent);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("BOOKING")) {
            callContent.put("Booking", text.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        /* You can perform some action in this method
         * for example to reset some sort of Collection
         * or any other variable you want. It gets called
         * every time a document end is reached. */
        SAXParsingFun.setHashMap(feed);
    }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

There are a lot of explanations on StackOverflow about how to parse a XML file I have left that out and just shown you the more interesting part; the content handler.

Now most of the interesting parts are commented so you can understand what I'm trying to do.

I have implemented the interface `ContentHandler` just to show you that there are more methods available, maybe you'll need one of them in the future. You can however extend from the class `DefaultHandler` instead and just overwrite the needed methods. All you do is basically check for the occurrence of certain tags and then trigger certain events upon that. If you want to preserve the order of the elements in the XML file then you simply use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example... looks good and I think I am getting to understand it. Eclipse doesn't like SAXParsingFun.setHashMap(feed); I imagine this isn't part of SAX but unclear how to fix...

Comment: Oh sorry that was my fault. It is part of another class which I used to initialize the parsing process. Thats just a way to send the HashMap to the other class. I've actually only explained how the ContentHandler works.

Comment: I wonder if I can ask a further question regarding this? I very much like the method you introduced to me, it seems to work well. However, after my <period> ... </period> tags I have another tag which I felt wasn't needed to mention. This is <banners><banner></banner></banners>. If nothing is there I get <banners />. However, my code fails whenever it reaches these tags regardless of values. Eclipse opens another tab with: "ExpatParser.startElement(String, String, String, int, int) line: 50" & "Source not found". I can't find where to get to any exceptions thrown... are you able to help?

Comment: @neildeadman: So the parsing fails whenever the content handler reaches the `<banners>` tag?

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: Sorry for delay in replying... I am having no end of problems with Eclipse. Sorted most of them, but I can't seem to stop it complaining about the startDocument() method @Override. It says it needs to override a superclass??? I'll get back to you when I have sorted this and am able to confirm your question.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: I started from scratch using your example and now have a working prototype. Thanks very much!! Never got to the bottom of issue I mentioned... at least it works now!!