# Parsing RSS feed to android application

Tags: android, parsing, rss

I'm building a hunting application for which I need weather information in form of a RSS feed from [this](http://www.meteo.si/uploads/probase/www/fproduct/text/sl/fcast_si-region_latest.rss) site.

I've used the code from [this](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/19/android-simplified-source-code-for-parsing-and-working-with-xml-data-and-web-services-in-android/) site and it list the feeds, but when I click on an item it doesn't connect it to the site for more information. I would like to get temperture and wind information but I don't know how to because I'm a beginer to programming.

I would very much appreciate any help especially in form of a code that would solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

Comment: Why don't you show us the code you have thus far, and point out where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: I've used this code: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/downloads/ which I than exported to eclipse and changed the following string to get RSS from page: static String feedUrlString = "http://www.meteo.si/uploads/probase/www/fproduct/text/sl/forecast_si_latest.rss";

Comment: Got it working thanks. It was missing a bit of a code - onListItemClick ... that's why I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code To fetch a RSS Feed from a URL and list it in a listview in android.

You need first to create a class that extends ListActivity, and then put this code:

```
    // Initializing instance variables
    headlines = new ArrayList();
    links = new ArrayList();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.RSS-Feed-URL-HERE");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
             * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
             * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
             * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
             * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
             *
             * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
             */
        boolean insideItem = false;

            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Binding data
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

    setListAdapter(adapter);


}
public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
    }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download and check my project on [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ozak.spormix). This project is about some Turkish sports channel. It is like all in one application.

You can check source code of project on [github](https://github.com/aknkaplanoglu/Sportmix).

Answer (score -1):

You can just go to any popular weather website, such as Weather.com, and look for their API section. Most websites provide their API to use to develop apps. Weather.com's API section actually instructs you through the process of implementing it.