# Fetch RSS from web and parse it

Tags: java, android, xml

This is probably because a lack experience with both Java and Android development, but I'm looking for a way to fetch a RSS feed over the internet and parsing it, so I can display a list of entries in my app.

A lot of Googling showed me a lot of different results, but all of the suggested solutions seems incredibly large and I don't seem to get the general idea of these large systems.

Downloading a couple of samples supplied me with 3 or more (up to 16) .java files that I had to implement into my project just to fetch and parse an XML file - this seems highly overkill to me, but maybe thats the only way to go?

In short - is there no *simple* way of doing each of these things?

Comment: The answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android may help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

Comment: @Octavian - this helped me further with my project... thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short - is there no simple way of doing each of these things?

Taking the XML parsing as an example, the solutions you found try to parse as many different types of XML files as possible.  XML files with multiple name spaces.  XML files that are not well defined, possibly with missing tags.

You could certainly code a simpler XML parser, because you only need to parse one type of XML file, from the RSS service you're interested in.

There's the good, fast, and cheap [project triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle).  No matter how hard you try, you can get at most two of the three.  Substitute simple for good, and small for cheap, and you'll see that you wind up with slow, meaning a custom solution.