# How to parse a XML file

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML response that I'm getting but I couldn't find a solution for it.

Can anyone help me out?

This is my response:

```
- <member>
  <name>AdURLs</name> 
- <value>
- <struct>
- <member>
  <name>small</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://www.jumptap.com/images/cg-windowshade-collapsed.jpg</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://mobilesitelinkexchange.com/images/stories/320x50mobile_standard.gif</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>
  <name>large</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_5pkoVwxuN90/S-RpGWWgshI/AAAAAAAACoU/HlB9I5WOo4g/s400/iphone_jd1003.jpg</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_5pkoVwxuN90/S_vW6bHZgMI/AAAAAAAACqs/CpQ05gcYtTA/s320/iphone-ps5032.jpg</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>
  <name>medium</name> 
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
  <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Ads-300x250.gif</string> 
  </value>
- <value>
  <string>http://www.wrestling-online.com/images/ads/300x250/nomercy2008.jpg</string> 
  </value>
  </data>
  </array>
  </value>
  </member>
  </struct>
  </value>
  </member>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

Comment: Not really a duplicate: SAX is just one approach.

Comment: @PontusGagge You're right. Still I think that this will answer his question.

Comment: Parsing XML on Android
http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/parsing_xml_on_android/

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the article "Working with XML on Android": http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

It describes popular ways to parse XML in Java: DOM and SAX approaches. I recommend to use SAX approach if you don't need to modify XML document: it's faster and less memory consuming.