# How to parse following code using SAXparsing in android?

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

```
<channel>
 <pubDate> <![CDATA[ 1301565012]]>  </pubDate>
 <name><![CDATA[ Nanopress]]> </name>
 <link><![CDATA[ http://www.nanopress.it ]]> </link>
<description> <![CDATA[ Tutte le ultime news di Nanopress ]]>  </description>
<language><![CDATA[ it ]]> </language>
 <item> <ID>0</ID> <url>
 <![CDATA[ http://www.politica24.it/articolo/giustizia-prescrizione-breve-caos-alla-camera-il-video/10129/ ]]> </url>
<category><![CDATA[ NanoPress ]]> </category>
 <title> <![CDATA[ Prescrizione breve: caos alla Camera ]]>  </title>
</channel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

Answer (score 0):

The package `org.xml.sax` is included in the Android SDK, you can parse xml like if you were in a basic Java application.

Create an class which extends `DefaultHandler`, instanciate a `SAXParserFactory` and start the parsing

```
SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();

parser.parse( xml, handler );
```