# parsingproblem in android saxparsing

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);
    if (itemFound==true){
        // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_title:     
                item.setTitle(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_description:
                item.setDescription(strCharacters);
                break;  
            case state_link:
                item.setLink(strCharacters);
                break;  
            case state_pubdate:
                item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                break;  
            default:
            break;    
        }    
    } else {
        // not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_title:
            feed.setTitle(strCharacters);
            break;
            case state_description:
            feed.setDescription(strCharacters);
            break;
        case state_link:
            feed.setLink(strCharacters);
            break;
        case state_pubdate:
            feed.setPubdate(strCharacters);
            break;  
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    currentState = state_unknown;
 }
```

Please tell me how to parse (&) I am not able to parse & in this

Comment: Please remove all the blank spaces and format the code...

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly, what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495735/how-to-get-data-using-sax-parsing-in-android/7495787#7495787

Answer (score 0):

Try it.. it ll help you.

private StringBuffer curTag = new StringBuffer();
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

```
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Test_tag")){ 
            System.out.println(curTag.toString());
        }
}
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        curTag.append(CharBuffer.wrap(ch, start, length));
    }
```