# XML parsing in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I was trying to make an app which has a component that will make an HTTP request and receive a XML file. I need to parse the file to display some data. I was using MIT App Inventor. How can I do that using the app inventor? If it is not possible by that approach then how I can do it in traditional manner?

And is it possible to import MIT App Inventor project to another IDE like Eclipse?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use saxParser.see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser

Comment: Does it need to receive XML?   @ZiG gave you a good way to receive JSON. There were examples that parsed XML but App Inventor has support for reading JSON  and csv

Comment: It needed to receive xml at that point. Fortunately I got a workaround on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hard code it like JSON-

https://imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/web-component-json-response-on-app-inventor

No, you can not import in Eclipse.

Comment: to import an App Inventor project into Eclipse, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444959/tips-to-shift-from-app-inventor-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Taifun's link is broken, but the new link can be found here: [App Inventor Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!category-topic/app-inventor-developers-library/libraryprojectsai-with-support-documents/D5HTBzgyoDE)

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for the updated link!

Answer (score 0):

Importing an app inventor to eclipse project is possible but with some limitations.It's a java bridge project(uses Java Bridge library)  which converts existing MIT app inventor project to Java.

Follow the link to convert:
[https://appinventortojava.appspot.com/login/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqNTc4DVYW8)

Video Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqNTc4DVYW8

Comment: Please, add some essential parts from links you have provided, to your answer.