# Tips to shift from App Inventor to Eclipse

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, app-inventor, android-sdk-tools

I am very good with AppInventor to build Android apps. I have good knowledge of C++ and little  knowledge of Java and GUI building in Java. Suggest me how should I shift from App Inventor to Eclipse to build Android apps? Which path should I follow? Is building in Eclipse similar to building in AppInventor like defining different components and then handling their events? Or is it much more than that? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the **AppInventor to Java Bridge project** at [java.appinventor.org](http://java.appinventor.org), details see below

> About:
>
> The AppInventor to Java Bridge project is an addition to
>   AppInventor that creates a Java written version of the application
>   from an existing application created through AppInventor. After
>   creating an application through AppInventor,the user can download a
>   version of the application that is written in Java, which uses the
>   JavaBridge* library .
>
> What Our Application Can Do:
>
> - Create an Android project in JavaBridge using AppInventor
> - Applications that use texting, internet and/or sound are supported
>
> Limitations:
>   - Location aware applications not yet supported
>   - Nested lists are not yet supported, and will produce incorrect code

**UPDATE**: the newest version of that tool can be found here: [java.appinventor.org](http://java.appinventor.org)

Comment: The page you link to is not public.

Comment: links updated, the newest version of the tool can be found here: [java.appinventor.org](http://java.appinventor.org)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you should check out the **"ALTERNATE Java Bridge"**.  The regular one, built originally by the app inventor team has long since been abandoned.  Another programmer picked up the torch and has steadily been using, and improving the bridge for some time.  I have been using it myself for 2 years and it is fantastic.

The google project is at: **https://code.google.com/p/alternate-java-bridge-library/**

and the google discussion group is at : **http://groups.google.com/group/alternate-java-bridge-library-discussion**

I would just go to the google project site above and ready the tutorial.  It is very easy to get started, and he is really good about answering questions for newbies (and i can assist with that as well).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the **[App Inventor Java Bridge](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/app-inventor-instructors/EKZOZLeIavs/KIjf5kMAbwkJ)**.
 Check out the link for lots of information, also see [here](http://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/howto-using-ai-javabridge/)...

> **The Google App Inventor Java Bridge**
>  The App Inventor Java Bridge helps
>   make a transition from developing Android applications with App
>   Inventor for Android, to developing with Java and the Android SDK.  It
>   lets you incorporate App Inventor components into apps that you create
>   in Java with the standard Android SDK tools.  If you’ve been using App
>   Inventor and know some Java, then the Java Bridge is a good way to get
>   started with the SDK, because building with App Inventor components
>   hides many of the complexities of the Android framework.   As you gain
>   experience, you can switch over to regular SDK development and create
>   apps that harness the full power of Android.

Here another link:
http://code.google.com/p/apptomarket/ and you also find videos about the Java Bridge on Youtube, for example [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0hq7yuH2EE)