# Integrating widget code in AppInventor decompiled code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-service, app-inventor

I frequently use the MIT AppInventor, as I am not too used to Java, but it lacks features.
So can anybody tell me how, if I want to add homescreen widget or a system service into my app, how do I do it? I have decompiled the app using a software similar to apktool but the code is not at all close to a normal Android application code. Can't even recognize components and methods from it.
Please help

Comment: this is unfortunately not possible with App Inventor, [star issue 55](http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=55), see also [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16552831/1545993) concerning how to convert an App Inventor project into Java code