# How to be more specific in XML Parsing?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I need to extract the value from "condition" but the one that's under "current_conditions".
Here is the code I have right now. It extracts value from condition but from "forecast_conditions". By the way i'm using SAXParser.

```
if (localName.equals("condition")) {
    String con = attributes.getValue("data");
    info.setCondition(con);
}
```

Here is the XML.

```
<current_conditions>
    <condition data="Clear"/>        
</current_conditions>

<forecast_conditions>
    <condition data="Partly Sunny"/>
</forecast_conditions>
```

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser

Answer (score 1):

Which parser do you use? If you use XmlPullParser (or any SAX style parser), you can set a flag when you encounter `current_conditions` START_TAG and check whether this flag is set when you check for `condition`. Don't forget to reset the flag when you encounter `current_conditions` END_TAG.

Comment: I use SAXParser. How do I set a flag?

Answer (score 0):

I'll second XmlPullParser - it's very easy to understand.

Here is some code for you case (not tested)

```
public void parser(InputStream is) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(is, null);

        boolean currentConditions = false;
        String curentCondition;

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("current_conditions")) {
                currentConditions = true;
                } 
                else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("condition") && currentConditions){
                    curentCondition = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,"Clear");
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("current_conditions"))
                    currentConditions = false;
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```