# Accessing Wordpress data from Android app?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, xml-rpc

Scenario: Making an Android app using data from a website built with Wordpress.  The way it's used will be much different than the website itself, but uses most of the same data, so I need more than just a simple WebView.  The site uses Wordpress to it's fullest CMS capabilities, it's much more than just a traditional Wordpress blog.

I know WordPress has been building a fairly robust XML-RPC API to get posts, pages, custom post types, categories, tags, custom taxonomies, media, comments, options, etc ( wordpress xmlrpc api codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API ).

I'm a web developer, but I know my way around Java.  Unfortunately, I haven't developed much on Android besides following some tutorials and playing around with a few things.

I looked at the official Wordpress for Android app (repository here: https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser#trunk/src/org/xmlrpc/android ) to see how they gather all the appropriate data, but the client they've developed is far more than I need, and I can't exactly pop it in like a .jar and go with it.

So I suppose my question is this:  Has anyone done this before?  What kind of client did you use, a prepackaged one, or a custom one?  I know similar questions have been asked before, but I also know a lot of the improvements to the WP XML-RPC API were added in the latest version of Wordpress (3.4), so there's not a whole lot of info out there, but any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having the same problem while trying to make an app for a website built on PHP/mySQL. I think you can check XML Parser

[How to parse XML using the SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser/4828765#4828765)

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

However for my website I am trying to use Jsoup to parse the html directly and populate listview.

[extract text from HTML segment using standard java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447082/extract-text-from-html-segment-using-standard-java)

Comment: Thanks, those links were helpful.  I ended up also using axmlrpc ( https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC ), and iterate through the Object or Object[] I get back from WordPress's XMLRPC API Methods getPost/getPosts with a bunch of HashMaps.

Comment: @LOLapalooza:may i know how did u implement it in your android code.How to use axmlrpc and call the methods in my native android app.I tried , but im not able to fetch data from my word press site.i dont know where im goin wrong .pls suggest