# extract text from HTML segment using standard java

Tags: java

I'm receiving a segment of HTML document as Java String and i would like to extract it's inner text.
for ex:  **hello  *world***   ----> hello world

is there a way to extract the text using java standard library ?
something maybe more efficient than open/close tag regex with empty string?
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to parse HTML but a dedicated parser like [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Using a regex will usually work at fist test, and then start to be more and more complex until it ends being impossible to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use regular expression to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use for instance [jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/). It has a convenient way to select elements from the DOM.

> **Example**
>   Fetch the Wikipedia homepage, parse it to a DOM, and select the headlines from the In the news section into a list of Elements:
>
> ```
> Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
> Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
> ```

There is also a HTML parser in the JDK: [javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/Parser.html), which could be applied like this:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new URL(webpageURL).openConnection().getInputStream());
ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
parserDelegator.parse(in, harvester, true);
```

Then, dependent on what kind you are looking for: start tags, end tags, attributes, etc. you define the appropriate callback function:

```
@Override
public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag,
        MutableAttributeSet mutableAttributeSet, int pos) {

    // parses the HTML document until a <a> or <area> tag is found
    if (tag == HTML.Tag.A || tag == HTML.Tag.AREA) {

        // reading the href attribute of the tag
        String address = (String) mutableAttributeSet
                .getAttribute(Attribute.HREF);

    /* ... */
```

Answer (score 2):

I will also say it - don't use regex with HTML. ;-)

You can give a shot with [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) , this is a open source.