# using SAX parser, how do you parse an xml file with out some foreknowledge of the structure of the xml?

Tags: java, android

is there a way to implement the sax parser without passing the names of the elements in the xml as it is done in getChild method or equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)?
Or
is there a way to find out what are the names of tags in an xml and then pass it to Sax methods.

Comment: Even if you could, how do you know what the tag represents?

Comment: You should know what elements you are parsing!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828765/1631457

1) is android sax parser example(don't anger me)

scroll down a little bit and you will see

2) org.xml parser example(i think you want this usage).