# Android - Parser XML using SAXParser

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am trying to use the API for our system in an Android Application.
I have this XML :

```
<item>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <description>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="http://abc.com/image1.jpg" width='80' height='80' /></td>
                <td>This is summary 1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </description>
    <link>http://abc.com</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 13 Mar 2013 13:42:42 +0700</pubDate>
</item>
```

Plz show me how to get elements in tag **< description>** using SAXParser:

- Element 1

  `src="http://abc.com/image1.jpg"`
- Element 2

  `<td> This is summary for title 1</td>`

Comment: I don't know how to get 2 elements above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole package for using a SaxParser here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html

Please see here for tutorial: [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

Comment: I've added a link to a tutorial here at stackoverflow.com