# How to parse a JSON object from inside <string> tag?

Tags: android, json

I want to parse through JSON, but the problem is, that the json object is located inside a `<string>` tag. How can I get the JSON object from it?

```
<string>
    { "SubListList" : {
        "SubList" : [ 
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "6",
                "Name" : "ANAESTHETICS",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "87",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "6",
                "Name" : "Berris",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "93",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "18",
                "Name" : "Dentsply",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "92",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "2",
                "Name" : "INFECTION CONTROL",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "88",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "3",
                "Name" : "LABORATORY PRODUCTS",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "89",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "1",
                "Name" : "SURGICAL SUNDRIES",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "90",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            },
            { 
                "Description" : null,
                "Items" : "6",
                "Name" : "X-RAY PRODUCTS",
                "PPLID" : "4",
                "SubListID" : "91",
                "poSubListItemList" : "clsSubListItemList"
            }
        ] } 
    }
</string>
```

Comment: Where is the <string> tag in the above code...

Comment: What do you mean by "json object is inside a <string> tag" ??

Comment: jst see the link i hv posted

Comment: For this you have to first parse using XML parsing then get the JSON string and then pare it using JSON parsing.

Comment: plz follow the link i hv posted...there u wl get <string> tag

Comment: i hv used XMLParser class..bt no solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply read the response into string, then remove the `<string>` and `</string>`

Here's a little snippet :

```
String response = response_from_URL
response = response.replaceAll("<string>", "");
response = response.replaceAll("</string>", "");
```

You might want to check the `response` string on LogCat, to do this, add the following code below the above snippet.

`Log.d("json", response);`

There you can check whether the tags are gone or not, if it is gone, then you can parse the `response` as JSON.

Good Luck ^^

Comment: a gd idea...bt a bit more elaboration will hlp me a lot..coz i m new in android..

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Regex` to get the string or `SAX` to parse the xml file, and then use `new JSONObject(String)` to parse JSON

Comment: any referral or link or a further xplntn would hlp.. @lee wong...i wnt to get string through SAX parsing...

Comment: try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser/4828765#4828765)

Comment: i hv seen this example bt sorry to say that it didnt hlpd me...bt thnx fr ur hlp....still stucked up with the prblm.......