# How to save multiple activity's edit text into a single file and again restoring back on pressing button

Tags: android

There are 4 activity and some edit text in each activity and i want to save all these edit text into a file on pressing one button and again have to restore all these on pressing other button

Comment: Post your code what have you tried. What is error ?

Comment: why don't you use `SharedPreference`?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference is a good idea. see this ([How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values))

Alternatively you think of other File IO.

Android also provide XML parser that could be another option depend on your requirement i guess. For SAX see this([How to parse XML using the SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser))