# Replacing XML Nodes in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML document in a foreign language and another XML document in English. I am trying to replace some nodes in the foreign document with nodes from the English document and export the document.

I have been working on this for days now and have tried countless things form importing both documents into text with a Scanner, BufferedReader, etc. with no good results.

I'm at a loss on what else I can try. I have searched for days and have nothing. Maybe what I'm trying to do cannot be done although it seems simple enough. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you need some XSLT to transform your message

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as it was a clear question with a correct, and accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them into DOM objects, then use [XPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) to locate and select nodes, to copy values between them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to replace and what you mean by "export", I would use an XML parser like SAX using the following algorithm

```
For each node that you read
    Replace attributes or text as necessary
    Write it out to the the a new XML file
```

There are many tutorials out there on how to use SAX, such as this one: [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

If the "replacements" you need to do are very straightforward like "all `<tag>` objects under `<parent-tag>`" then maybe building the DOM and using XPath would work, but if your replacements are very arbitrary and unstructured then I'd go with parsers.