# Unable to Parse Parent / Child Elements using SAX XML Parser (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I'm attempting to following this example of SAX XML Parser: [How to parse XML using the SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser)

However when debugging - some items are returning null. I have verified they are contained within the XML file I am connecting to - but I believe I've set my getVideos/setVideos parameters incorrectly and I'm not sure how they might be corrected.

### XML Data

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<response>
<cmd>getVideos</cmd>
<success>1</success>
<NumberOfVideos>4</NumberOfVideos>
<Videos>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iPod</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/omv/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/omv/1/06087297988b.m4v
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_mpeg4</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/omv/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/omv/1/b5ed9e7100e2.mp4
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_sorenson</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/omv/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/omv/1/2a8e64b24997.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iTunes</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/omv/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/omv/1/6c7f65254aad.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
</Videos>
</response>
```

### SAX Parser Related Java:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("response")) {
        // add it to the list
        response.add(cmd);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
        cmd.setSuccess(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("numberofvideos")) {
        cmd.setNumberOfVideos(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
        cmd.setVideos(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
        cmd.setVideo(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videoname")) {
        cmd.setVideoName(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videourl")) {
        cmd.setVideoURL(tempVal);

    }
```

...

```
public class SAXXMLParser { 
    public static List<Cmd> parse(InputStream is) {
        List<Cmd> response = null;
        try {
            // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
            XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                    .getXMLReader();
            // create a SAXXMLHandler
            SAXXMLHandler saxHandler = new SAXXMLHandler();
            // store handler in XMLReader
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
            // the process starts
            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            // get the `Video list`
            response = saxHandler.getResponse();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return Laptop list
        return response;
    }
}
```

...

```
 public class Cmd {
private String success;
private String cmd;
private String videos;
private String video;
private String numberofvideos;
private String videoname;
private String videourl;


public String getCmd() {
    return cmd;
}

public void setCmd(String cmd) {
    this.cmd = cmd;
}
public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getNumberOfVideos() {
    return numberofvideos;
}
public void setNumberOfVideos(String numberofvideos) {
    this.numberofvideos = numberofvideos;
}
public String getVideos() {
    return videos;
}
public void setVideos(String videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
}
public String getVideo() {
    return video;
}
public void setVideo(String video) {
    this.video = video;
}
public String getVideoName() {
    return videoname;
}

public void setVideoName(String videoname) {
    this.videoname = videoname;
}
public String getVideoURL() {
    return videourl;
}

public void setVideoURL(String videourl) {
    this.video = videourl;
}
```

Please let me know if any additional information is required. I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sets the member video instead of videourl in setvideourl method
public void setVideoURL(String videourl) {
    this.video = videourl;<<----
    This.videourl = videourl;
}

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that : ( Thank you!