# how to get text within tag when parsing xml

Tags: android, xml

I am getting an XML text from a web service. I have successfully loaded the stream XmlPullParser object by getting `parser.setInput(con.getInputStream(),null);` where parser is my XmlPullParser object and con is my connection to the URL.

I am reading the stream but I don't know how to get specific parts to it. This is how the XML file looks like:

```
    `<response> 
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>order|war (antonym)</synonyms></list> 
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>harmony|concord|concordance</synonyms></list> 
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>public security|security</synonyms></list> 
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>peace treaty|pacification|treaty|pact|accord</synonyms></list> 
</response>`
```

I would like access the text within in the `<synonyms>` tags but not sure how to do that. This is what I have:

```
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = parser.getName();
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

                stringToBeDisplayed.add(parser.getText()+"\n");
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
```

But the above code gets the Text within the `<category>` tag and the `<synonyms>` which I dont want. I only want the text enclosed in the `<synonyms>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
String tagValue = null, tagName = null;
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      switch (eventType) {
          case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
               tagValue = xmlPullParser.getText();
               break;
          case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
               tagName = xmlPullParser.getName();
               if (tagName != null && tagName.toUpperCase().equals("SYNONYMS")) {
                        // do something with tagValue
                        stringToBeDisplayed.add(tagValue);
               } 
               break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It works. Can you tell me in my code why a blank value comes into my stringToBeDisplayed List since I dont understand why I am getting a blank string after

Comment: btw why are you doing this +"\n"? just do stringToBeDisplayed.add(tagValue).. edited my answer. Please accept if you think it works.

Comment: Best one that I've searched In google about my issue, tnx. Why don't accepted like best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a SAX XML Parser and Handler.

If you search on google there are thousands of tutorials. Here's [one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser--mobile-9041). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser) there is an explanation between two different SAX implementations: the `org.xml.sax` or `the android.sax` and explain pro's and con's of both with examples