# Xml parsing issue in java android

Tags: java, android

I try to parse xml from `str` with this methods:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();    
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();    
InputSource is = new InputSource();    
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str.toString()));    
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

and in `str` i have :

```
<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>
```

but always in `db.parse(is);` the app is crash.
but if i put instead :

```
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str.toString()));
```

this:

```
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>"));
```

it work perfect. any idea?

Comment: What excatly is "the app is crash"? Any exception?

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@41369600)

Comment: are you sure Str has that xml string? Did you printout? If str is really there, I would change str.toString() to str.toString().trim(); and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know what is `str`.If str is already a string then not need to use `str.toString`.

or if str is any TextView or EditText then use str.getText().toString.Then it will work.And if you have third case in spite of these two then please specify this so that i could edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to switch to SAX XML parser rather than DOM Parser . As its faster ,uses less  memory and easier to implement (Dnt think of using advance parser like STAX as they are not supported in android ). Check this link out [ANDROID: Parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839372/android-parsing-xml)