# How to parse xml file on android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Does android has some dom/sax parsers?

E.g. of xml file:

```
<A>
   <B>
   </B>
   <C>
   </C>
</A>
```

My file is  more complex  but i this was a simple example.
Does android have some dom/sax parser?

Comment: It does. A simple search in Google would get you to [http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).

Comment: why dont you google something first and the post any question on this forum ..... its such a simple query and lots of code would be already present on internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ANDROID: Parsing XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839372/android-parsing-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android also supports **SAXParser**, and the code will **not differ** from a normal java program.

SAX parser use callback function (org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler) to informs clients of the XML document structure. You should extend DefaultHandler and override few methods to achieve xml parsing.
The methods to override are

- startDocument() and endDocument() – Method called at the start and end of an XML document.
- startElement() and endElement() – Method called at the start and end of a document element.
- characters() – Method called with the text contents in between the start and end tags of an XML document element.

For a working code visit: 
[XML parsing using SaxParser with complete code](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/08/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

### [Android Xml Parsing Tutorial][1]

```
         we can parse xml files in android is very simple. In market there are many xml parsers are available to parse xml data in android. But simplexml is one of the best xml parser in android.
```

1. Create one Android Application Project.
2. Download simple-xml.jar from internet.
3. Prepare your xml file.

## Employee.xml

```
<Employees>
   <Employee>
     <id>01</id>
     <name>jagadeesh</name>
     <salary>00000</salary>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
     <id>02</id>
     <name>jaggubai</name>
     <salary>00000</salary>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
     <id>03</id>
     <name>jaggudada</name>
     <salary>00000</salary>
   </Employee>
<Employees>
```

4. Now you need to create two pojo classes. Because here we are using two things one is group of employees and another is individual employees. So, for group of employees we need to create Employees.java and for individual employees Employee.java.

## Employee.java

```
public class Employee{
    @Element
    public String id;
    @Element
    public String name;
    @Element
    public String salary;
}
```

### Employees.java

```
@Root
public class Employees{
    @ElementList(inline=true, entry="Employee")
    public List<Employee> listOfEmployees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SAXParserExample extends DefaultHandler{

List myEmpls;

private String tempVal;

//to maintain context
private Employee tempEmp;


public SAXParserExample(){
    myEmpls = new ArrayList();
}

public void runExample() {
    parseDocument();
    printData();
}

private void parseDocument() {

    //get a factory
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        //get a new instance of parser
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        //parse the file and also register this class for call backs
        sp.parse("employees.xml", this);

    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Iterate through the list and print
 * the contents
 */
private void printData(){

    System.out.println("No of Employees '" + myEmpls.size() + "'.");

    Iterator it = myEmpls.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }
}


//Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    //reset
    tempVal = "";
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
        //create a new instance of employee
        tempEmp = new Employee();
        tempEmp.setType(attributes.getValue("type"));
    }
}


public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch,start,length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
        //add it to the list
        myEmpls.add(tempEmp);

    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
        tempEmp.setName(tempVal);
    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Id")) {
        tempEmp.setId(Integer.parseInt(tempVal));
    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Age")) {
        tempEmp.setAge(Integer.parseInt(tempVal));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SAXParserExample spe = new SAXParserExample();
    spe.runExample();
}
```

}

for xml 
`<Personnel>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Seagull</Name>
        <Id>3674</Id>
        <Age>34</Age>
   </Employee>
  <Employee type="contract">
        <Name>Robin</Name>
        <Id>3675</Id>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Crow</Name>
        <Id>3676</Id>
        <Age>28</Age>
    </Employee>
</Personnel>`

Check this link : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152