# How to Parsing XML content with url

Tags: java, android

I have url www.test.com/test/xml

in xml file have

```
<channel>
  <item id="001">
  <title>a001</title>
  <actorlist>
     <actor>
       <name> a1 </name>
       <name_drama> d1 </name_drama>
     </actor>
     <actor>
       <name> a2 </name>
       <name_drama> d2 </name_drama>
     </actor>
    <actor>
   <gallery>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg1.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg1.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg1.png  </glarge>
     </gimages>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg2.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg2.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg2.png  </glarge>
      </gimages>
     <gimages>
   <gallery>
</item>
<item id="002">
  <title>b002</title>
  <actorlist>
     <actor>
       <name> a12 </name>
       <name_drama> d12 </name_drama>
     </actor>
     <actor>
       <name> a22 </name>
       <name_drama> d22 </name_drama>
     </actor>
    <actor>
   <gallery>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg12.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg12.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg12.png  </glarge>
     </gimages>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg22.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg22.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg22.png  </glarge>
      </gimages>
     <gimages>
   <gallery>
</item>
<item id="003">
  <title>c003</title>
  <actorlist>
     <actor>
       <name> a13 </name>
       <name_drama> d13 </name_drama>
     </actor>
     <actor>
       <name> a23 </name>
       <name_drama> d23 </name_drama>
     </actor>
    <actor>
   <gallery>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg13.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg13.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg13.png  </glarge>
     </gimages>
     <gimages>
        <gsmall>  sg23.png  </gsmall>
        <gmedium> mg23.png  </gmedium>
        <glarge>  lg23.png  </glarge>
      </gimages>
     <gimages>
   <gallery>
</item>
<channel>
```

How to  Parsing to

item1 = title:001,name:a1, name_drama:d1, name:a2,name_drama:d1 . . .

item2 = title:002,name:a12, name_drama:d12, name:a22,name_drama:d22 . . .

item3 = title:003,name:a13, name_drama:d13, name:a23,name_drama:d23 . . .

Comment: This is a little unusual.  If you tell us why you want the result like that, we might be able to find alternate solutions.  Basically, parsing the XML is some work, and I would not generally go through that much work only to put the result in a comma-sep string.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839372/android-parsing-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to parse you can use java Dom if memory is not the issue else go for java SAX parser.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser) is the example.

Answer (score 0):

Android projects can use any Java library that can be used to parse XML.

[Lots of examples of parsing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)